# get mongodb fields in particular order in php

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I get data from mongodb in php and display fields in table. Can I get fields in php from mongodb in the order I set, for example, when the order of fields I send in fields doesn't effect othe order of fields I display them:

```
$cursor = static::getMongoCollection(false)->find($query)->fields($fields);
```

For example it displays in the same order now matter if I use:

```
$fields = array("field1" => 1, "field2" => 1, "field3" => 1)
```

or

```
$fields = array("field3" => 1, "field2" => 1, "field1" => 1)
```

I need in my application to display fields in different order. Is there a way to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP driver just returns the fields from MongoDB in whatever order MongoDB sends them.  So, regardless of how you select the fields you wish to return, the data sent back won't change (unless you alter the fields list of course).  Why don't you just order the results yourself after they are returned?

Comment: Adam, do you mean that I can't get fields from mongodb in order I define. For example, in sql I can get fields in order something like SELECT fields1, fields2, fields3 or SELECT fields3, fields2, fields1.

Comment: Ability to set order of fields to get data makes it much simler, otherwise I have to process every row of returned data for example, when I display them.

Comment: For example, if fields are returned in the order I need, I can simply display them.

Comment: Unless it is a case of many, many fields though I can't see why this is a problem.  As it stands, there is currently no way to alter this behavior in the driver or in mongoDB.  You can try asking for a change to that (jira.mongodb.org) but that will take a significant amount of time.  Therefore the only way to achieve what you want at the moment is to do the sorting of the fields yourself, or create a wrapper to do so and abstract it that way.

Comment: It's interesting why such functionality has been added to mongodb (which is usual for example in rdbms). Are there any difficulties to implement it specific to mongodb?

Comment: I don't think there are difficulties per se - it's just that it is quite trivial to do the ordering of fields on the client side.  However, that's what the voting mechanism is for in the MongoDB Jira project - if enough people agree with you that this is useful and would improve their quality of life, then it will get voted up and have a higher priority for implementation.

Comment: Returning data with order fields in record like in SQL seems very useful and can make code more simple (there is not need to process and order fields manually). It doesn't seem elegant at all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need `ksort` ?

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Comment: As I have said in the post I pass to in ordered $fields, but it doesn't affect the order of fields I get. I gave examples of two arrays of fields I pass, but in the second case the order of the fields doesn't change.

Comment: ksort will not work. The OP is trying to get the results of a MongoDb query in the order they are requested. In MySQL if you do `SELECT col_a, col_z, col_y, col_b FROM table` your results will almost certainly be in the order selected (i.e col_a, col_z, col_y, col_b). The problem with MongoDb is that it doesn't necessarily return the columns in the requested order and `ksort` will not really help.